# Prevent jQuery .load() if hash is visited

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

I am loading pages within a content `div` with `.load()` function and using `window.onhashchange` event to detect if the user is navigated.

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
   hash(window.location.hash.replace('#', ''))
}
```

and

```
function hash(s) {
    $('.panel-body').fadeOut(100).load(s+'.php').fadeIn(100)
}
```

Some of the pages takes long to load everytime. I don't want them to be reloaded (bypass `.load()` function) if the state is already cached. Any workaround?

Comment: Add cache headers from server or use jQuery ajax cache options.

Comment: AS a side note, to Pinal's suggestion, you don't need to mess with the ajax cache options since the default behavior of a GET request is to Cache, if proper headers are returned from server. so you just need to ensure the server is returning the proper caching headers for content that you want to be cacheable.

Comment: I don't know anything about managing cache headers from server. Any easy reading source or syntax example?